# How can I get the ProcessSerialNumber of an OSX process using Python?

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to post an event using CGEventPostToPSN, but I'm having trouble getting the correct process serial number.  I have found the process that I care about via NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchedApplications(), but I don't know what to pass in to CGEventPostToPSN as the processSerialNumber argument.

I see the fields NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberHigh and NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberLow, but I'm not sure what to do with them.  I've tried just passing them in as a tuple of (NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberHigh, NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberLow), but that didn't seem to have any effect.

The code looks something like this:

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPostToPSN
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGMouseButtonLeft
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateMouseEvent

my_process = filter(lambda x: x, [x if x.get('NSApplicationName') == 'My Process' else None for x in  NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchedApplications()])[0]
high_psn = my_process.get('NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberHigh')
low_psn = my_process.get('NSApplicationProcessSerialNumberLow')
my_psn = (high_psn, low_psn)
theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx, posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
CGEventPostToPSN(my_psn, theEvent)
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: is there a `ProcessSerialNumber` object with `highLongOfPSN` and `lowLongOfPSN` fields, like in Objective-C?